# cvsps missing in msysgit 1.7.11?

Tags: git, msysgit

i'm trying to import our old cvs repository into a git repo by following these instructions:
http://www.gromacs.org/Developer_Zone/Git/Migrating_a_CVS_repository_to_GIT

i'm using windows, so i tried to use msysgit. i could log in to my cvs repository, but when running the git-cvsimport command, it tries to execute cvsps which is apparently missing in the msysgit installation. where can i get it, and why is it missing?

Answer (score 2):

It is missing because cvsps has not been ported to msys or native windows. There may be a cygwin version around but you are likely better to perform the conversion on a unix machine. Once you repository has been converted you can use it on Windows.

cvsps makes use of `fork()` which is a problem for msys programs and will require significant effort to be ported to native windows. For some repositories or for a one-off conversion you may find [cvs2git](http://cvs2svn.tigris.org/cvs2git.html) is a better conversion tool. I do not know if this can be run on Windows either but as it is written in Python it may well do so.